# Shell script to create a new SQL dump

Tags: mysql, macos, bash, shell, sh

I am currently using MAMP pro and i want to create a simple terminal script (or a .bat file like on the PC) which allows me to create a sql dump (where i go in and preconfigure the database name) and it automatically creates me the `.sql` file.

This is what i know so far:

1: The script should first visit `cd /applications/MAMP/library/bin`

2: When it in that directory, it should run the following

`./mysqldump -u root -p databaseName > /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/db.sql`

Finally, in that directory, when i click the script, it should not replace the older file, but create a new one, maybe just add the date or a integer after it.

Is that possible?

Apologies, i have no idea the best way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have this:

```
#!/bin/sh
TS=$(exec date '+%s')
cd /applications/MAMP/library/bin && \
    ./mysqldump -u root -p databaseName > "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/db.$TS.sql"
```

It would create files in the form of `db.(timestamp).sql`.

If you want to have other forms, just changhe the `date` command. `'+%s'` specifies the format to produce which is the timestamp. You can see other formats with `date --help` or `man date`.

Comment: What's the advantage of `$(exec date...)` instead of `$(date ...)` ?

Comment: Just optional to prevent extra forking. Without `exec` the shell makes a process tree of `shell->subshell->date` while with `exec` it just becomes `shell->date`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations! Isn't it a `bash` construct -- or is it available on plain old `sh`?

Answer (score 1):

Just a variation on the other answer (vote for it!). You don't have to change directory to execute `mysqldump` :

```
#!/bin/bash
TS=$(exec date '+%s')
/applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysqldump -u root -p databaseName \
                  > "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/db.$TS.sql"
```

Please beware that you have both `/Application` and `/application` directories. Depending your FS case sensitivity this might be an error.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the OSx?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /applications/MAMP/library/bin && mysqldump -u root -p databaseName >   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/db.sql
```

After this, you'll need set the permission to your script:

```
chmod +x your_script_file
```

Now, you can call...

```
./your_script_file
```

or

```
sh yout_script_file
```

If you want to replace the old file, this command will do this, because the new file name is the same the older file name